# Problems with 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, string, sorting, io, priority-queue

I have a textfile which contains

> id_is_g0000515
>
> num_is_0.92
>
> id_is_g0000774
>
> num_is_1.04
>
> id_is_g0000377
>
> num_is_1.01
>
> id_is_g0000521
>
> num_is_5.6

Its suppose to sort the data in by "g0000515" and by numbers only "0.92" without the string "id_is_" and "num_is_". It gives me an error TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable. Can someone help me?

```
    import os, sys, shutil, re


def readFile():
    from queue import PriorityQueue
    q = PriorityQueue()
    #try block will execute if the text file is found
    try:
        fileName= open("Real_format.txt",'r')
        #for tuple in fileName:
            #fileName.write('%s',tuple)
        for line in fileName:
                for string in line.strip().split(','):
                    if string.find("id_is_"):
                        q.put[-4:] #read the ID only as g0000774
                    elif string.find("num_is_"):
                        q.put[-4:] #read the num only as 0.92

        fileName.close() #close the file after reading          
        print("Displaying Sorted Data")
        #print("ID TYPE       Type")
        while not q.empty():
            print(string[30:35] + ":     " +q.get())
            #print(q.get())

            #catch block will execute if no text file is found
    except IOError:
                print("Error: FileNotFoundException")
                return

readFile()
```

Comment: Please include the *full traceback* of the exception, so we don't have to guess where this happens. It sounds as if you are trying to use a method with `[...]` subscription access, rather than call the method with `(...)`.

Comment: What did you expect `q.put[-4:]` to do? You are using the `PriorityQueue.put()` method as if it is a list there, that won't work.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Project Python/SortingAlgorithmBetaV2.py", line 32, in <module>
    readFile()
  File "F:/Project Python/SortingAlgorithmBetaV2.py", line 15, in readFile
    q.put[-4:]
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information like that.

Comment: q.put[-4:] is to extract the substring of  "id_is_g0000515" or "num_is_0.92" so that i only get g0000515 and 0.92 without the string

Comment: You'll need to slice `string` then, and call `q.put()` with the result of that slice.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to slice the `PriorityQueue.put()` method here:

```
q.put[-4:]
```

That won't work; method objects are not sliceable. I think you wanted to slice the `string` variable and put all but the first 4 characters in the queue instead:

```
q.put(string[4:])
```

Note that I used a *positive* number there; you don't want the list 4 characters, you want everything but the first 4.

When the string starts with `"num_is_"`, you'll need to skip more characters; `num_is_` is 7 characters, not 4:

```
q.put(string[7:])
```